# After upgrading iphone app to ipad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I upgraded my iphone app an now it is compatible with iOS3 and ipad. I created two copies of my project. I upgraded one copy to two device-specific application and second copy to one universal application.

Now two device specific app runs in ipad and and appears with 1x zoom. it shows a 2x zoom button which makes it fit to the ipad screen. It also changes the size of UI Element. Is it the default behavior of ipad application?

While one universal application opens in ipad withot showing 2x zoom button. It automatically fits the screen size to ipad screen size but the problem is that it doesn't change size of UI elements like datepicker etc. Is it the default behavior of ipad application?

As far as I know ipad application should open with full screen without showing 2x zoom and it should also change the size of UI elements. So both of them are not working fine. Am I wrong? If not, how do I fix this problem.

If I am wrong please tell me which universal app is working correctly for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIDatePicker` is not supposed to be shown in a screen-filling fashion on the iPad. In fact, even if you manage to get it filling the entire screen (which is possible), your app will get rejected as this is not the way you should be using it on the iPad. Depending on the context, it might be a good idea to consider using a `UIPopoverController` for showing the `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: my two device specific app shows datepicker in appropriate format even after clicking 2x zoom. But I don't have iPAD. Is it common that an iphone app opens with 2x zoom button in ipad? iF yes, then I don't need to make any change.

Comment: Yes, if you deploy an iPhone app to an iPad it will show the 2x button.